# Rails 3 and Jquery's rateit plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to add a star rating system within my recipe app, each user can rate a different recipe once. I have read that Jquery's rate it is a good place to start. http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm My question is regarding how to get this to work in rails 3, my initial thoughts are

Setup a rating model which will look like so

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :recipes
has_many :users
attr_accessible :recipe_id, :user_id, :number  
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :recipe_id
end
```

Set up model relationships

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :ratings
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :ratings
end
```

Controller

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController

 def new
 @rating = Rating.new
 end

 def create
 @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])
  if @rating.save
    redirect_to my_recipes_path, :notice => "Thanks #{current_user.name} Recipe successfully Rated."
 end
```

As mentioned before I am thinking of using the Jquery plugin rateit, which can use HTML range inputs

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" step="0.5" id="backing2">
<div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#backing2"></div>
```

My thinking is that to submit a star rating to the model I need submit the values as a hidden field, something similar to

```
<%= form_for @rating do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :recipe_id, :value => recipe.id %>
<%= f.submit 'Rate Recipe' %>
<% end %>
```

What im not sure on is how to link the rating given to a value to put in the model.Ideally i would like to achieve this via an Ajax request.

My associations may be incorrect as a lot of my code maybe? Having never approached something like this before I was hoping that someone could point me in the right directoion or at least point out my mistakes so far

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about using The Rateit Gem

https://github.com/ouvrages/rails-rateit

I have not used it but just did a google for "Rateit Gem" and that was the top hit.

Comment: would prefer not to use a gem, would like to get a full understanding of combining this process with Ajax, and how i can click say the third  star and it would post the value 3 to the model